# Formatting Excel Cell by Value in other Cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to highlight certain names in a spreadsheet based on the role they hold within an organization. For example, I would like to define a person as "president," and then have their name be highlighted whenever I type it elsewhere in the sheet. I would just conditionally format using the person's name, but I would like it to automatically change when a new person becomes president.

Comment: If you appoint anyone the position as "president", I'd assume you do this in some kind of table-format which is searchable through formulae. In this case a `VLOOKUP()` based CF-formula could do when applied to all cells on the worksheet. Mind you, CF is volatile and when done on "elsewhere in the sheet" could become sluggish if that would mean the entire worksheet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.